# methods for undertaking complex calculations in Java

Tags: java, apache-commons-math

I have to implement some relatively complex formulas in a Java application.  The inputs to these formulas are include up to 30 or so variables.  Some of these variables in their natural form are integers, some are reals with a precision of around 3 to 4 decimal places.  I am using commons-math for the functions, but I am wondering about precision and convenience:

Would it be best to convert all variables integers to Double prior to passing to the formula methods.  This way there is a consistency within the formulas and secondly can I safely use Double for 3 to 4 dp precision?  Is there a "best practice" for implementing complex math in Java?

Comment: In general, using ints and doubles together in math in java will "promote" the int to a double, so no loss of precision occurs.

Comment: @kevinsa5 Is this true of Integer and Double?  Should I be using int and double?

Comment: Integer and Double are when you need formal classes -- for normal math operations, int and double are standard.  They usually get converted between each other when necessary anyway.  See "autoboxing" with java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to convert variables `Integers` to `Double`. Initialize all the variables as `Double` because if you are having a part in formula where it is just dividing 2 `Integers` and is added to the result of 30 variables, then it will lose the values for decimal places. So it best to use `Double` for mathematical purposes where Decimal places are significant to produce a correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

For floating point calculation with precission... I would suggest to use BigDecimal. Because Double and Float are know for their lost of precision.
The following snippets illustrates the problem.

```
System.out.println( 0.1f + 0.1f + 0.1f + 0.1f + 0.1f + 0.1f + 0.1f + 0.1f + 0.1f + 0.1f );
System.out.println( 0.1d + 0.1d + 0.1d + 0.1d + 0.1d + 0.1d + 0.1d + 0.1d + 0.1d + 0.1d );

1.0000001
0.9999999999999999
```

Multiplying 0.1 ten times, you expect to get 1. But its not.

Comment: +1, This problem is not related Java. Floating point implementations are hardware based and follows IEEE standard. So, native floating point values and precision losses, or  BigDecimal and  performance losses ...